# Why isn't my else if statment working for margin-top in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, menu, onclick

My function works for making the menu drop down from the top but I want to be able to click it and make it go back up again. I'm achieving this with changing the margin-top of the element.

Here's the function:

```
    <!--Mobile Menu On Click-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function mobile_menu(){
    if($('mobile_menu_container').css('margin-top') !=== '0px'){
    document.getElementById('mobile_menu_container').style.marginTop="0px";
    } 

    else if($('mobile_menu_container').css('margin-top') === '0px'){
    document.getElementById('mobile_menu_container').style.marginTop="-260px";
    } 
    }
    </script>
```

Here's the html:

```
<a href="#" onClick="mobile_menu()"> 
<p id='tap_to_view'>
Tap To View Menu<br />
</p>
</a>
```

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery with plain JavaScript?

Comment: What does `$('mobile_menu_container').css('margin-top')` return?

Comment: In your html the id is `tap_to_view`, in your javascript it is `mobile_menu_container`. This may be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

`$('mobile_menu_container')` returns all `<mobile_menu_container>` elements (that is, most likely, nothing). If you want to get the element with the id mobile_menu_container, you must write: `$('#mobile_menu_container')`. (Notice the `#`).